# Solution for Windows service failover system on MS Azure

Tags: .net, azure, windows-services, redundancy

We have a server environment with two different virtual machines each running a subset of our Windows services (about 50 in total split equally) created in .NET. What I'm looking for is the best way to automatically start the remaining services on the other VM should the one of them go down.

The reason we need this solution is that we're running these VMs on the cloud (MS Azure) which can get restarted semi-regularly. These services are also fairly hard to implement as actual horizontal scaling systems (especially the legacy services). So what we're after is essentially a form of redundancy system.

We've considered doing a custom solution ourselves using our centralized SQL database (also on Azure), but we'd rather prefer to use an existing solution if possible. 
Google has yielded very little on the topic. So far the only tool we've found that allows this is using Docker with some extensions. But Docker also has many more features that we don't need and has a non-trivial barrier to entry (but is still an option obviously).

Comment: with failover clustering you can cluster Windows services, which looks like what you are after

Comment: @4c74356b41 From what I could find clusters are only supported on older versions of Windows server (~2003), but maybe I misread the msdn documentations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952401.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Automation to poll the VM with the services and when a service is offline, do X on another VM. Azure recently released Task Watcher(subset to automation) that can poll with 1 minute granularity. note that it is in preview but it gives you sommething that you don't have today.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/azure-automation-watcher-tasks-public-preview-now-available/

Comment: no, this is definitely a nowhere near production grade solution.